# Proof of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, proof

Could someone provide me a reference, preferably a book, where I can find detailed proofs and explanations of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (including the two-sample variant) and the derivation of the $D_n/D_{m,n}$ statistics used?

Comment: I really liked the treatment of the topic in Peter Sprent & Smeeton's [Applied Nonparametric Statistical Methods](http://books.google.be/books/about/Applied_Nonparametric_Statistical_Method.html?id=M59rMlCM4FIC&redir_esc=y)